# Is this RTMFP delay acceptable?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video, p2p, rtmfp

I have a project that required me to use flash p2p video using RTMFP Flex.
When we tested the application the quality was good but there was noticeable delay (1-2s)
with the audio and the video. I tweaked the settings to lower the quality to achieve acceptable latency but the clients are comparing it with Skype video.

Is there something that I missed?
What is the acceptable latency with rtmfp?
Is Skype superior to flash p2p video?
Can you list the factors related to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to achieve latency around 0.1s, which is not noticeable during conversation.
Few tricks, that I have used:

1. Do not use RTMFP groups. They can't handle real time communication because of multicaastWindowDuration.
2. Use bufferTime = 0 on every used NetStream.
3. framesPerPacket = 1 on Microphone.

You could also try videoReliable = false, audioReliable = false on NetStreams.

You should see following resources:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/acoustic-echo-cancellation.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/real-time-collaboration.html

Comment: #1 - I used both with/without groups and groups does have more latency. #2 I did. #3 - I will try. videoReliable = false - I have tried.

I'm wondering what is the bandwidth/internet speed your application encounters?

Comment: I had best results with at least 4Mbit up/down bandwidth, pings around 50ms. I'm using H2640 at around 640x480@10fps, quality set at 80%. I'm also using speex as sound codec.